# how many implementations a scala method can have?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm new in Scala. I come across with this question:
If side effects (outputs, global variables ...) are not taken into account, how many implementations can the below method have? how can I figure it out in general?

```
def g[A,B,C](x: A,y: B,f:(A,B) => C): C
```

Comment: And can you can come up with one?

Comment: Lets think about it. If I have two parameters, namely `x: A` and `y: B`, and a function that given a tuple of `A` and `B` produces a `C`, and the return type of my method is `C`, how many ways can I compose these together to produce my output type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure it out in general by going backwards from your return type, so you look at `C` and try to look for where it might come from, we can see that `f` itself returns `C`, but it requires us to give it an `A` and a `B`, so now we look for those and we find them only once, which gives us the answer that there's only one way to produce a `C` and therefore only one way to implement this function. If we had two values of `A`, we'd get two different implementations.

Now of course this kind of ignores the fact that you also implement it using `null` or an infinite number of ways using `asInstanceOf` casts. So if you have to be super exact there are 1* implementations of this function.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ill-posed even without `null`s, `asInstanceOf`s and throwing exceptions. For every natural number `n`, you can simply append `.swap.swap` to `(x, y)` `n`-times in the following implementation (example for `n` = 1):

```
def g[A, B, C](x: A, y: B, f: (A, B) => C): C = {
  val (xx, yy) = (x,y).swap.swap
  f(xx, yy)
}
```

You can do the same thing by inserting arbitrarily many `identity` functions at various places. Or by using `_1`, `_2` projections and `(-,-)`-constructors (or, in general, repeatedly applying non-productive eta-expansions and beta-reductions of your choice).

Comment: Well, `while (true);` always is a valid implementation, right? I think the OP was referring to extensional behaviour, otherwise "implementation" could also include different whitespace formattings of which there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know, is it "valid"? This thing doesn't even terminate, so it's not even a "function", but rather something like "partial function with empty domain of definition". Once one has defined what "valid" means, one would have to define what "equal" means (whitespace? up to var renaming? same AST? same rewritten "minimal" representation? extensional equality?), otherwise one can't count anything. My point was exactly that: one doesn't even need non-termination or any `null`s or casts to make the question ill-posed. It requires much more precise setup.